# Problems trying to import a package

Tags: python, module, package

I have the following project structure:

```
Project |
        |- sim |
        |      |- out |
        |             |- main.py
        |- libs |
                |- __init__.py
                |- plus.py
```

Inside `plus.py` there is a function called `sum(a,b)` that returns the sum of 2 numbers. I'm trying to import the module `plus.py` into `main.py` to the able to call this function, however I'm getting the following error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Here is the code inside `main.py`:

```
from ...libs import plus

a = 1
b = 5

c = plus.sum(a,b)
print(c)
```

One of the solutions I found is to add the project directory to path, but I'm trying to avoid that.

I'm using VSCode to call python, this could be also a useful information.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Added `__init__.py` files in `sim`, `out` and `Project` directories as @ThePjot suggested and the error remains. Now the project structure is in the following form:

```
Project |
        |- __init__.py
        |
        |- sim |
        |      |- __init__.py
        |      |- out |
        |             |- __init__.py
        |             |- main.py
        |- libs |
                |- __init__.py
                |- plus.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty.

Comment: what's in the __init__.py?

Comment: You're missing `__init__.py` files in `sim`, `out` and in the `Project` directories.

Comment: Hello @ThePjot, thanks for the help. I've created `__init__.py` in the `sim`, `out` and `Project` directories and the ImportError message is still appearing.

Comment: Hello @XxJames07-, the `__init__.py` file is empty.